# turtlebot is not moving with published messages on cmd_vel

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a simple turtle_move.cpp file that is suppose to make the turtlebot move in a square. The turtlesim program moves like its suppose to fine with my source code. I am using ROS groovy and a turtlebot 2.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


 // Initialize the ROS system and become a node.
  ros::init(argc, argv, "turtle_move");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Create a publisher object.
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(
    "cmd_vel", 1);

  // Seed the random number generator.
 

  // Loop at 2Hz until the node is shut down.
  ros::Rate rate(.5);
  // Create and fill in the message.
  geometry_msgs::Twist vel;
  vel.angular.z = 0.0;
  vel.linear.x = 0.0;    
do{
    
// Publish the message.
pub.publish(vel);
rate.sleep();
vel.angular.z = 0.0;
vel.linear.x = 5.0;

ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"
    << " linear=" << vel.linear.x
    << " angular=" << vel.angular.z);

 
pub.publish(vel);
rate.sleep();
vel.angular.z = (float)1.5708;
vel.linear.x = 0.0;

      // Send a message to rosout with the details.
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending random velocity command:"
    << " linear=" << vel.linear.x
    << " angular=" << vel.angular.z);

    // Wait until it's time for another iteration.
    rate.sleep(); 

    }while(ros::ok());
}
```

The turtlebot is suppose to follow a square path. I have verified that my turtlebot is on and functional by running the turtlebot_teleop program first and everything was running fine. But when I try to run my program to make the turltebot follow a square it doesn't work. I have made sure that all my dependencies are accurate, my CMakeLists.txt includes an executable turtle_move.cpp file that runs just like I ran my code for the turtlesim which is working.

I noticed that a launch file exists does anyone know if this might be the reason my code is not controlling the turtlebot.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173516/turtlebot-is-not-moving-with-published-messages-on-cmd_vel/) by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you verified that topics are hooked up correctly rostopic info or rqt graph? And have you verified that they're being published correctly with rostopic echo?

You also appear not to be spinning anywhere. There's a tutorial for writing a publisher here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

And debugging tools can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-06-13**:
No the program I have created is not creating a topic that connects to the cmd_vel node on the turltebot. When I launch the rqt graph there is no connection established.

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-06-13**:
Thank for the info, I was able to debug the problem looking up different peoples problems

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
Choog, how did you solve the problem? I have the same and I do not achieve to connect the cmd_vel node on the turtlebot.
Thanks for your help,

Silvia

---

Originally posted by [silvia](https://answers.ros.org/users/11341/silvia/) with karma: 21 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [beluga](https://answers.ros.org/users/39391/beluga/) on 2019-01-23**:
Hello, I am having the same issue. Any solutions?

**Comment by [beluga](https://answers.ros.org/users/39391/beluga/) on 2019-01-23**:
Ah ok, I solved my issue. I needed to publish to /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi topic instead of /cmd_vel.